# Issue converting HTML to aspx page as the button in the webform is not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

[image]

The HTML code for this form (left hand side) is like below.

```
                    <div class="lp-element lp-pom-form" id="lp-pom-form-410">
                        <form action="#" method="POST">

                                <div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_name">
                                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="text form_elem_name" placeholder="Name">
                                </div>

                                <div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_email">
                                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="text form_elem_email" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>



                        </form>
                        <a class="lp-element lp-pom-button" id="lp-pom-button-411" href="#"><span class="label">GET MY DEMO</span></a>
                    </div>
```

I am trying to convert it to aspx and the back-end code for it into vb.net shown below.

```
                      <form id="form1" runat="server">

                            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="uxForm">

                                <div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_name">

                                      <asp:TextBox ID="uxName" runat="server"  CssClass="text form_elem_name" placeholder="Name"    />

                                </div>
                                <div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_email">

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="uxEmail" runat="server" CssClass="text form_elem_email" placeholder="Email"  />
                                </div>


                        </asp:Panel>

                        </form>
```

The problem is that I cannot convert the get my demo button in to asp button.

I have tried the following:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSave" CssClass="lp-element lp-pom-button"   Text="Get My Demo" />
```

but it just become invisible like the picture (right hand side form)

I have also tried

```
    <a class="lp-element lp-pom-button" id="save" runat="server"><span class="label">GET MY DEMO</span></a>
```

But then also the button goes invisible and the text get my demo is in the name field as shown in the 2nd picture.

[image]

What has gone wrong and how can I correct it? **the button goes invisible..even without css class**

For your information I have not created the vb.net codes yet. Could that be the issue?

---

CSS

```
#lp-pom-button-411 {
  display:block;
  border-style:none;
  behavior:url(/PIE.htc);
  border-radius:9px;
  left:0px;
  top:251px;
  z-index:16;
  width:348px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#f7941d;
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#fd494b,#fb2c2f);
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(#fd494b,#fb2c2f);
  background:-ms-linear-gradient(#fd494b,#fb2c2f);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(#fd494b,#fb2c2f);
  background:linear-gradient(#fd494b,#fb2c2f);
  box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px #ff9697,inset 0 -1px 2px #c72325;
  text-shadow:1px 1px #7a0404;
  -pie-background:linear-gradient(#fd494b,#fb2c2f);
  color:#fff;
  border-width:undefinedpx;
  border-color:#undefined;
  font-size:25px;
  line-height:30px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:Raleway;
  text-align:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}


  .button{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 17px 34px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 52px;
    width: 123px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    background: red;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fe4d4f, #fb2d2e);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fe4d4f, #fb2d2e);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fe4d4f, #fb2d2e);
    background: linear-gradient(#fe4d4f, #fb2d2e);
    margin-left: 49px;
    text-shadow: #000000 1px 0px 1px;
  }
  .button:hover{
    background: red;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f13839, #ee2526);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f13839, #ee2526);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f13839, #ee2526);
    background: linear-gradient(#f13839, #ee2526);
  }
```

picture 3
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnGetDemo" CssClass="lp-element lp-pom-button lp-pom-button-411"><span class="label">GET MY DEMO</span></asp:LinkButton>
```

My guess is that the "label" class on the span has something to do with it.

EDIT:
I changed the LinkButton markup a bit AND do change the CSS aswell to:

```
.lp-pom-button-411 {
 display:block;
 border-style:none;
 behavior:url(/PIE.htc);
 border-radius:9px;
 left:0px;
 top:251px;
 z-index:16;
 width:348px;
 height:50px;
 position:absolute;
 background-color:#f7941d;
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#fd494b,#fb2c2f);
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(#fd494b,#fb2c2f);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(#fd494b,#fb2c2f);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(#fd494b,#fb2c2f);
 background:linear-gradient(#fd494b,#fb2c2f);
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px #ff9697,inset 0 -1px 2px #c72325;
 text-shadow:1px 1px #7a0404;
 -pie-background:linear-gradient(#fd494b,#fb2c2f);
 color:#fff;
 border-width:undefinedpx;
 border-color:#undefined;
 font-size:25px;
 line-height:30px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:Raleway;
 text-align:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: i just tried your solution . the button goes invisible and the GET my demo text is on the name field like the 2nd picture

Comment: hi .. the button i can see now .. i have edited the post  to include what its look like.. see picture 3 .

Comment: one question.for the click action for this button will this work? -   Protected Sub btnGetDemo_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetDemo.Click

Comment: Make sure you have declared the button as WithEvents in your page class.

Comment: Hi Bashabi, yes that code should work just fine. With regards to the CSS/layout of the button, if you haven't found the solution yet, could you post the entire CSS? It might very well be something with the <form> tag that messes things up. Or if the design is from a tutorial/article, post the link for it and I'll have a go at it.

Comment: JaggenSWE : Thank you ... there are 2 css files used in here.  as they are very long so i am posting the link for this css here....   http://t.p.mypeoplebiz.com/mpblite/files/styles/signup_main.css  http://t.p.mypeoplebiz.com/mpblite/files/styles/page-defaults-9470e7c.z.css

Comment: This will make the button look as you want it:
https://jsfiddle.net/7grL25zh/ Remember to change the event (onClick) to whatever method you have in codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

You are not create button event, create button evetn like this and try:

```
<asp:button id="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Get My Demo" CssClass="lp-element lp-pom-button" onclick="btnSave_Click">
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am getting this error 'btnSave_Click' is not a member of 'ASP.mpblite_signup_asp

Comment: Hi i have added the relavant css in my post. please have a look

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="uxForm">
        <div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_name">
            <asp:TextBox ID="uxName" runat="server" CssClass="text form_elem_name" placeholder="Name" />

        </div>
        <div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_email">

            <asp:TextBox ID="uxEmail" runat="server" CssClass="text form_elem_email" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>

        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Get My Demo" CssClass="lp-element lp-pom-button" />

    </asp:Panel>


</form>
```

Comment: the button goes invisible.. like the right hand side form in the 1st picture